# Serving large static files with Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Sinatra can serve files from a static directory with the `set :public, 'your_directory'` command, but how can I replicate this in a new route?

Importantly, this new route needs to respect byte ranges too! Any ideas? I feel like I should be able to leverage the already present code in the static serve part of sinatra.

Comment: to serve static files you would use httpd or something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I can just use `send_file` ([see here](http://sinatra.rubyforge.org/api/classes/Sinatra/Streaming.html#method-M000022)) - but if anyone has any other suggestions I have open ears!